# SPUtility not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, sputility

I am trying to get SPutility to work in Sharepoint online. I could not get any scripts to work in neither script editor nor content editor web parts. I don't have access to custom forms advanced mode editing (yet - i hope i will get it soon from the admin). I managed to find a workaround by using Form HTML webpart and editing its source code and putting my script there. jQuery works and gives me the test alert, but nothing happens when i try to get an alert from SPUtility. ( I also tried using some functions on the form like autocomplete but no luck there as well. Here's the code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 alert("jQuery");
alert($().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[FOR USE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255004(v=vs.85).aspx)
jQuery 1.11.x (SPServices 2013.01+) RECOMMENDED

jQuery 1.10.x (SPServices v0.7.2+)

NOT jQuery 1.9.x

[Your plugin 'jquery-3.2.1.js' isn't work](http://sympmarc.com/2011/07/08/adding-jqueryspservices-to-a-sharepoint-page-step-one-always/).

```
var thisUserAccount = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldName: "Name",
    debug: false
});
```

If you want to use this SPServices library in a site scope, upload to the “Site Assets” library and import it into master page should be a good practice.

About analyzing your webpage's network traffic in IE Developer Tools:

[Analyzing your webpage's network traffic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255004(v=vs.85).aspx)

Also, you can get information from the console of the browser using IE Developer Tools, it will give you more information if there will be any error in this page.

Comment: I changed it to jquery-1.11.1.min.js and its still not working I'm afraid.

Comment: What is F12 console, errors?

Comment: There is 8 errors and 8 !'s but i thing that one is of importance:
SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined
NewForm.aspx (684,1)

There is also: Tag cannot be self-closing. Use an explicit closing tag. a couple of times

And a couple of SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/forbidframing.htm and other files

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for help. It turned out that the reference i used was incorrect as my site is a subsite of the site collection and it entered /siteassets of the whole site collection, not my subsite. I found it thanks to the IE traffic tool you showed me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kloggy your welcome :))